# Find Predecessor in a BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I want to search recursively and efficiently a predecessor in a binary search tree without using parent pointer.
I give the root of the tree and a certain data (that can be contained or not in the BST) as parameter of the function.

I'm having troubles because if the BST does not contain the data, the function should give in output the maximum value smaller than it.

```
Node *recPredecessor(Node *root, int data, Node *pred){
    if(root->key > data){
        return recPredecessor(root->left, data, pred);
    }
    if(root->key < data){
        return recPredecessor(root->right, data, root);
    }
    if((root == NULL) || (root->key == data)){
        if(root == NULL){
            return pred;
        }
        if(root->key == data){
            if(root->left != NULL){
                return bstRecGetMax(root->left); //this func return node with Max key
            }else{
                return pred;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you traverse the tree, simply keep the predecessor..

Comment: I forgot to say it should be done recursively

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Add a parameter to your recursive function called "parent" and pass the currently being visited node as one.

Comment: I posted the code i wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want the predecessor to node ***N*** in an in-order traversal sense, there are three possibilities:

1. **N** *has a left child*.  In this case, the predecessor is the rightmost element of ***N***'s left subtree.
2. **N** *does not have a left child, and there is at least one rightward step in the path from the root to* **N**.  In this case, the predecessor is the source node of the rightward step nearest to *N* on that path.
3. **N** *does not have a left child, and there are no rightward steps along the path to it from the root*.  In this case, ***N*** is the minimum element in the tree, so it has no predecessor.

What you must do, therefore, is track the source of the most recent rightward step (not necessarily the immediate parent) as an additional parameter to the recursive search function by which you find node ***N***.  When you reach ***N***, you will then have that ready to use in the event that ***N*** has no left child, and you can ignore it if ***N*** does have a left child.

Comment: It looks about right, @Diablo3000, but if you're going to check whether `root` is null then you should do that *before* trying to examine the members of node it points to.  Note also that the initial call to that function needs to pass `NULL` as the third argument; personally, I'd provide a wrapper function to hide that detail from the client.  In any case, do *test*.  Nothing beats thorough testing.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will wrap this function and will test it soon.