# Search and remove BST predecessor (or successor)

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, abstract-data-type

How can I recursively remove a predecessor (or successor) of a given data from a binary search tree? The data can be contained or not in the tree.

The function should return the key stored in the predecessor (or successor) node.

Comment: If the value is not in the tree, then it does not have a predecessor with respect to the BST, though it might have a predecessor with respect to values of its type.  Perhaps you mean something like "the node with the largest value less than the target value"?  This may seem pedantic, but it's important to couch the problem to be solved in clear terms in order to understand how to solve it, or even how to recognize a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you mean that you want to remove the node containing the largest value less than some target value ***t***, where ***t*** itself is not necessarily the value of any node in the tree, consider what results you may obtain by searching the BST for value ***t***.  There are three possibilities:

1. You find ***t***.  This boils down to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082214/find-predecessor-in-a-bst/56082561#56082561) -- you just have to have performed the same tracking you would in that case.
2. You arrive at a node ***N*** whose value is greater than ***t***, and that has no left child.  In this case, the tree does not contain ***t*** or any value between ***t*** and the value of ***N***.  It is therefore the predecessor of ***N*** that you want to remove, if it has one, so it again boils down to the situation of the previous question.
3. You arrive at a node ***M*** whose value is less than ***t***, and that has no right child.  In this case, the tree does not contain ***t*** or any value between ***M***'s and ***t***, so ***M*** itself is the node you want to remove.

Comment: So I have a function that returns my predecessor node and in another function I delete this node which means I have to traverse the tree again even if I know where is the node. There is a way to search and delete it ?

Comment: It is possible to write such a function, yes, @Diablo3000.  Presumably, it would be a hybrid of your existing deletion function and the predecessor-search function described here.  Details depend to some extent on the exact style of BST you've implemented, and overall they constitute too broad a question for SO.